# jquery animation movement loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get an animation i made with jQuery to infinitely loop but my code isn't working. If anyone could give suggestions that would be great!

```
function loop(){
    $('#frontPage').animate({marginLeft:"800px"},1500,loop);
}

loop();
```

Comment: what should the animation do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code loop will animate only once (at the first call) to `marginLeft` equals `800px`. After this it will try to animate `marginLeft` from 800 to 800. But if you add `+=` before animate, it will works:

```
function loop(){
    $('#frontPage').animate({marginLeft:"+=800px"},1500,loop);
}

loop();
```

Comment: It's actually `+=`, not just `+`, but yes.

Comment: Thanks, yes it is. Fixed.